# Third party to PeopleSoft SSO integration

Tags: peoplesoft

I have to write sign on peoplecode to make a service call by passing token (sent from third party) to API and get the responce (if token is valid responce will have username) in json format to create a PS_TOKEN.

I am fresher to peoplecode. How can I run HTTP POST request by passing token and get the response using Peoplecode?

Answer (score 1):

You would create a synchronous service operation in the Integration Broker.  The Integration Broker works best if you are sending XML or JSON.  If this is just a regular HTTP POST with fields then it can cause some issues with the Integration Broker.  I had a similar case and could not get the basic HTTP Post to work but instead ended up using HTTP POST multipart/form-data and was able to get that to work.

Steps I had to do to make this work.

1. Create a Message (document based or rowset based are both possible)
2. Create Service Operation and related objects
3. Create Transform App Engine to convert the Message to a HTTP POST multipart/form-data
4. Create a routing and modify the connector properties to send the content type of multipart/form-data.  Also call the Transform app engine as part of the routing.

The issue with a  application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST is that it seems PeopleSoft does another url encoding after the Transform, which is the last time you can touch the output with code.  This final url encoding was encoding the = sign in the form post which made the format invalid.

Your other option would be to write this is Java and call the Java class from within PeopleSoft (or mix the Java objects in with PeopleCode).  If you choose to go this way then the App Server needs to have connectivity to your authentication server.  My only experience with this is I had a client that used this approach and had issues under heavy load.  It was never determined the cause of the performance issue, they switched to LDAP instead to resolve the issue.